# How to give back a bounty, that I should not earn?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, bounty

Relating to this question [cygwin/race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260083/ruby-fork-exec-detach-do-we-have-a-race-condition-here/31505653#31505653)

I was writing my comment / request for more information, as the comment editor "told" me I had 100 chars too many, and I was not even ready.

So I decided to post my comment for more information as an answer.

I wrote this as first line / bold.

The one who asked, made a mistake, and gave me the bounty, but my assumptions were wrong (since I had only assumptions, I did not want to answer)

So now I have a bounty that I am not entitled to.

Is there a chance to give it back? I feel a bit like a thief, or like "take the bounty and run"

(P.S: if it was a "100K SO specialist", I'd have less bad feelings)

Comment: Open your console in your browser edit your reputation and then just don't reload anymore, just don't :)

Comment: You could always pass it forward, put another bounty on a question you're interested in or where you think one of the answers deserves some extra credit.

Comment: @Rizier123: why not reloading, I write a browser plugin, that does that for me ;-)

Comment: Don't mess with karma!

Comment: For goodness' sake, ignore the whole StackOverflow rewards system. It's designed for schoolchildren who won't do their work unless rewarded with a gold star. Take part in StackOverflow if you enjoy it, don't take part if you don't, and let others worry about earning brownie points.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Don't worry about it.

Reputation is only a *very* rough measure of anything, anyway. During your future SO "career", you'll gain many points you feel you didn't earn; you will also fail to gain a lot of points you may feel you *should* have earned (for excellent answers with hours of research on an obscure topic, for example).

No one else appeared to have a correct answer, either. So the user would have lost the bounty amount either way.

Perhaps they thought it better to give it to someone who  put an effort into answering (you) instead of no one benefiting from it at all.

No harm done.

Comment: Just so. Call it a credit against future awesome answers that don't get noticed.

Answer (score 10):

Bounties do not work that way : they are proposed by somebody for a limited time, but since that moment the bounty value is deduced from the promoter (I call him/her that way because it can be question asker or anyone else) rep **and this cannot be undone**.

Next, if promoter finds a question deserving the bounty until expiration time, he can manually award it. In that case the answerer receives the full bounty value. Here again nothing can be undone after manually awarding.

If the bounty has not been manually awarded at expiration time, the *best* answer with at least +2 will automatically receive half value of the bonus

References : [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Now to answer your question, it is clear that you cannot give it back. If it makes you feel bad, the best you can do is to try to improve your answer. For the rest, you tried to help, your answer is clearly more than a comment, and OP decided your answer was the best. If another user later posts another answer better than yours, you simply should :

- upvote it if it deserves it
- edit your own answer to reference it, saying that it was posted after bonus award but you thing it is better than yours

That way, even if the quality of that answer would not deserve the bonus per se, you will have done your best to improve the site. And if it is not enough for you to feel good, just do your best to improve the site, by flagging incorrect posts, duplicates, and also try to talk on meta. All that will indeed deserve the 50 points rep !

Comment: Nitpicking: This technically *can* be undone -- [diamond moderators can refund bounties](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties/27103#27103) and have been know to do so once in a full moon.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi : It is cited in the referenced link, but the link also says the do so for *exceptional circumstances* which IMHO is not the case here :-)

Comment: I'm curious - what kind of exceptional circumstances have been known to cause diamond moderators to refund bounties? Full moons are rather regular (sometimes as often as twice a month) so I feel like there must be some patterns that have become apparent in the few years that SO has existed.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Could be a good idea to ask a new question for that.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: Moderators will refund bounties on questions which ought to be closed, since bountied questions cannot be closed.