# How to give back a bounty

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have looked at the related questions, such as ["How to give back a bounty, that I should not earn?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300208/4843530)  And I agree with the apparent consensus that it is ok for @halfbit to keep those rep points.  But I think I have something different enough to merit asking this question again.

A very generous and prolific contributor recently asked for help with an algorithm.  I spent maybe two hours, figured it out and posted [an answer with a fiddle and a semi-decent explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31842286/4843530).  He expressed that the algorithm I provided was exactly what he needed and thanked me for it.  I dismissed his thank you and said he'd owe me a beer if we ever met in real life.  I meant that completely in jest.  I don't even like beer.  But today, in reply, he gave me a bounty of 500 rep points!

In halfbit's previous question, it was a matter of 50 points that had already been offered as a bounty, whereas I am dealing with ten times that, and these are points that were never offered as bounty, but given only after I made an ill advised joke.  In terms of the whole philosophy of what rep-points are for, I think this is a very different case.

From a quick glance at the OP's profile, he is generous in giving bounties, and his posts gather tons of views and upvotes.  I would probably trust his posts more than I trust my own.  I feel like I should give most if not all of that bounty back.  I could look through his answers and give bounties to them.

Is this appropriate?  It keeps to the whole rep-points = trust-level philosophy.  I don't want to offend him in his generosity, but I also don't want him to have done this because he felt obligated.  Giving generously can be a blast, and I would not want to take that away from him either, but it seems like way more points than my answer merited.  What would you do in my place?

Comment: Nothing should be done, he's generous, you helped him out. Take the "money" and run.

Comment: Pay it forward. Find an answer or two that have really helped you and provide the user a bounty.

Comment: If you don't want the points but don't want to give them back so as not to insult him.... I'm a taker for them (jk of course). Seriously though : the OP is allowed to give you 500 points if he wants. If you spent 2 hours on an answer, I think you deserve these

Comment: Your "schmenkyou" comment on the question on which you got the bounty may have sounded to the OP like you thought you were owed *more* than just thanks.

Comment: @Louis - yes.  I thought the impossibility of what I was asking for would make it clear I was joking, but in retrospect, maybe not so much.  Not the first time, nor last, that my foolish sense of humor will have put my foot in my mouth - up to my knee.  So, what to do?

Comment: @Deduplicator - Not a duplicate.  In my original post I acknowledge and linked to that question (see first paragraph).  But there are significant differences that change the whole dynamic of rep-points = trust-level.  If you read both questions, and consider the op's and the answerers on both questions and what this does to their rep-point levels, this is a very different situation

Comment: I doubt he felt any obligation to give you the bounty. Jokes about owing a beer aren't that uncommon, and he's given away almost 90% of the rep he's earned in bounties (this isn't the first 500 point one he's awarded). If it was me, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 10):

It is the user's reputation points. They can do what they want with it, assuming it's not propping up a sock puppet. This user is using the bounty to say your answer was very helpful.

---

If you feel uncomfortable receiving this windfall of reputation, you are also free to do with it what you want. (Again, assuming you aren't propping up sock puppets).

My suggestion is to pay it forward. Find an answer or two that has really helped you solve a problem. Provide that user with a bounty as a means of saying "thank you". One of the reasons for a bounty is to reward an existing answer. Utilize that reason when setting up a bounty. Doing this provides you with the peace of mind that you haven't earned undue reputation while also encouraging users to continue their good contributions.